# How do I work with data connections programmatically?

Tags: data-connection

How to create/update/read data connections in a SharePoint data connection library?

Comment: Do you think you could elaborate on your question? I think the more information you include, the better answers you will receive. Some things to think about: What is your current situation (environment, setup)? What are you trying to do? What have you tried already?

Answer (score 2):

Data connection are only xml files... treat them with SPFile objects and standard xml file processing (XDocument, XmlDocument, etc.)